# Bower 650 1300mm on Sony E-Mount?

Tags: sony, sony-nex

This super long telephoto lens has a nice price point.  Reviews seem satisfactory.

I am wondering if anyone has had any experience hooking it up to a Sony APS-C E-mount system, like the A6000, NEX-5, NEX-7, etc...

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/614835-REG/Bower_SLY650T_650_1300mm_f_8_16_Manual_Focus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used (on a NEX-3) its "little brother", the [500mm F/8](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/635278-REG/Bower_SLY500P_500mm_f_8_Manual_Focus.html) - well, under a different brand, but it's basically the same lens design made by [Samyang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samyang_Optics) and being sold under a dozen different brands for decades.

Most people would say that "cheap junk" is a more accurate description than "nice price point". The optical quality is adequate at most. Wide open, it's downright bad - and remember, wide open here already means F/8! And of course it's manual focus (and aperture).

Still, there are conditions where it will allow you to take shots that would otherwise require a lens that costs at least 10 times as much. If your camera has focus peaking (the ones you cite do, I think), your subject doesn't move and you have either direct sunlight or a decent tripod, then it can be useful.